# layout_weight is not working when using data binding text

Tags: android, data-binding, android-layout-weight

First of all, sorry about my poor english
I have a recyclerview with xml layout like this

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

    <variable
        name="township"
        type="com.test.feature.Area" />

</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@{township.name}"
        android:textColor="@color/agent_list_gray_1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btnRadio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I set text to the textview in Adapter class, and this is what I want
[what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtkls.png)

But if I use data binding with this line instead

> android:text="@{township.name}"

I got this 
[layout_weight is incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyCWT.png)

So does anyone know what's wrong with my code ?

There are another ways to archive this kind of UI but I really want to know why this won't work

Comment: Have you fixed this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use RelativeLayout and set the Textview to parentLeft and the EditTextview to parentRight for the spacing?

Comment: it's likely that will work, but I just want to know why layout_weight is not working with data binding

Answer (score 0):

It's weird! because I implemented your code and it worked. Maybe try wrapping it in a parent view same as below (I did it this way) :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/backgroundOrange"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@{township.name}"
            android:textColor="@color/textPrimary"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btnRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: I wrapped it up with constraintLayout like above and it still does not work to me. Do you use data binding to bind the text ?

Comment: @user2558303 Yep! I used an `ObservableField<String>` to bind the data to view.
Maybe the fact that you are using it on a list is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution is Simple.**

When inflating your layout if your layout is inside another layout pass container layout as parent in the inflate method.

If you don't, all attributes starting with `layout` will not work.

Your inflating code should look like this.

```
binding = FragmentTestBinding.inflate(layoutInflator,parent,false)
```